# How to make bash glob a string variable?

Tags: bash, shell-script, quoting, wildcards

## System Info

OS: OS X

bash: GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin16)

## Background

I want time machine to exclude a set of directories and files from all my git/nodejs project. My project directories are in *`~/code/private/`* and *`~/code/public/`* so I'm trying to use bash looping to do the `tmutil`.

## Issue

### Short Version

If I have a **calculated** string variable `k`, how do I make it glob in or right before a for-loop:

```
i='~/code/public/*'
j='*.launch'
k=$i/$j # $k='~/code/public/*/*.launch'

for i in $k # I need $k to glob here
do
    echo $i
done
```

In the long version below, you will see `k=$i/$j`. So I cannot hardcode the string in the for loop.

### Long Version

```
#!/bin/bash
exclude='
*.launch
.classpath
.sass-cache
Thumbs.db
bower_components
build
connect.lock
coverage
dist
e2e/*.js
e2e/*.map
libpeerconnection.log
node_modules
npm-debug.log
testem.log
tmp
typings
'

dirs='
~/code/private/*
~/code/public/*
'

for i in $dirs
do
    for j in $exclude
    do
        k=$i/$j # It is correct up to this line

        for l in $k # I need it glob here
        do
            echo $l
        #   Command I want to execute
        #   tmutil addexclusion $l
        done
    done
done
```

**Output**

They are not globbed. Not what I want.

```
~/code/private/*/*.launch                                                                                   
~/code/private/*/.DS_Store                                                                                  
~/code/private/*/.classpath                                                                                 
~/code/private/*/.sass-cache                                                                                
~/code/private/*/.settings                                                                                  
~/code/private/*/Thumbs.db                                                                                  
~/code/private/*/bower_components                                                                           
~/code/private/*/build                                                                                      
~/code/private/*/connect.lock                                                                               
~/code/private/*/coverage                                                                                   
~/code/private/*/dist                                                                                       
~/code/private/*/e2e/*.js                                                                                   
~/code/private/*/e2e/*.map                                                                                  
~/code/private/*/libpeerconnection.log                                                                      
~/code/private/*/node_modules                                                                               
~/code/private/*/npm-debug.log                                                                              
~/code/private/*/testem.log                                                                                 
~/code/private/*/tmp                                                                                        
~/code/private/*/typings                                                                                    
~/code/public/*/*.launch                                                                                    
~/code/public/*/.DS_Store                                                                                   
~/code/public/*/.classpath                                                                                  
~/code/public/*/.sass-cache                                                                                 
~/code/public/*/.settings                                                                                   
~/code/public/*/Thumbs.db                                                                                   
~/code/public/*/bower_components                                                                            
~/code/public/*/build                                                                                       
~/code/public/*/connect.lock                                                                                
~/code/public/*/coverage                                                                                    
~/code/public/*/dist                                                                                        
~/code/public/*/e2e/*.js                                                                                    
~/code/public/*/e2e/*.map                                                                                   
~/code/public/*/libpeerconnection.log                                                                       
~/code/public/*/node_modules                                                                                
~/code/public/*/npm-debug.log                                                                               
~/code/public/*/testem.log                                                                                  
~/code/public/*/tmp                                                                                         
~/code/public/*/typings
```

Comment: Single quotes stop shell interpolation in Bash, so you might try double-quoting your variable.

Comment: @ThomasN no, that does not work. `k` is a calculated string, and I need it stay that way till the loop. Please check my long version.

Comment: @ThomasN I updated the short version to make it clearer.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can force another round of evaluation with `eval`, but that's not actually necessary. (And `eval` starts having serious problems the moment your file names contain special characters like `$`.) The problem isn't with globbing, but with the tilde expansion.

Globbing happens *after* variable expansion, if the variable is unquoted, as here<sup>(*)</sup>:

```
$ x="/tm*" ; echo $x
/tmp
```

Another thing that happens for unquoted expansions is word splitting, which will be an issue if the patterns in question contain characters in `IFS`, usually whitespace. To prevent this issue, word splitting needs to be disabled by setting `IFS` to the empty string.

So, in the same vein, this is similar to what you did, and works:

```
$ IFS=
$ mkdir -p ~/public/foo/ ; touch ~/public/foo/x.launch
$ i="$HOME/public/*"; j="*.launch"; k="$i/$j"
$ echo $k
/home/foo/public/foo/x.launch
```

But with the tilde it doesn't:

```
$ i="~/public/*"; j="*.launch"; k="$i/$j"
$ echo $k
~/public/*/*.launch
```

This is [clearly documented](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Expansions) for Bash:

> The order of expansions is: brace expansion; tilde expansion, parameter and variable expansion, ...

Tilde expansion happens before variable expansion so tildes inside variables are not expanded. The easy workaround is
to use `$HOME` or the full path instead.

<sub>(* expanding globs from variables is usually not what you want)</sub>

---

Another thing:

When you loop over the patterns, as here:

```
exclude="foo *bar"
for j in $exclude ; do
    ...
```

note that as `$exclude` is unquoted, it's both split, and also globbed at this point. So if the current directory contains something matching the pattern, it's expanded to that:

```
$ IFS=
$ i="$HOME/public/foo"
$ exclude="*.launch"
$ touch $i/real.launch
$ for j in $exclude ; do           # glob, no match
    printf "%s\n" "$i"/$j ; done
/home/foo/public/foo/real.launch

$ touch ./hello.launch
$ for j in $exclude ; do           # glob, matches in current dir!
    printf "%s\n" "$i"/$j ; done
/home/foo/public/foo/hello.launch  # not the expected result
```

To work around this, use an [array variable](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Arrays) instead of a split string:

```
$ IFS=
$ exclude=("*.launch")
$ exclude+=("*.not this")
$ for j in "${exclude[@]}" ; do printf "%s\n" "$i"/$j ; done
/home/foo/public/foo/real.launch
/home/foo/public/foo/some file.not this
```

Though note that if the patterns don't match anything, they'll by default be left as-is. So if the directory is empty, `.../*.launch` would be printed etc.

---

Something similar could be done with `find -path`, if you don't mind what directory level the targeted files should be. E.g. to find any path ending in `/e2e/*.js`:

```
$ dirs="$HOME/public $HOME/private"
$ pattern="*/e2e/*.js"
$ find $dirs -path "$pattern"
/home/foo/public/one/two/three/e2e/asdf.js
```

We have to use `$HOME` instead of `~` for the same reason as before, and `$dirs` needs to be unquoted on the `find` command line so it gets split, but `$pattern` should be quoted so it isn't accidentally expanded by the shell.

(I think you could play with `-maxdepth` on GNU find to limit how deep the search goes, if you care, but that's a bit of a different issue.)

Comment: Are you the one answer with `find`? I actually am exploring that route too, as the for-loop is getting complicated. But I am having difficulty with the '-path'.

Comment: Credit to you as your info about tilde '~' is more direct to the main issue. I will post the final script and explanation in another answer. But full credit to you :D

Comment: @JohnSiu, yeah, using find was what first came to mind. It might be usable too, depending on the exact need. (or better too, for some uses.)

Comment: @JohnSiu, updated again, to explicitly mention an issue I think Stéphane was pointing out in the [comments](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/314804/how-to-make-bash-glob-a-string-variable#comment553302_314809) to another answer

Comment: Stéphane's comment is not very relevant in this case. You can check out my final script at the bottom. However I properly will try using `find` as that should eliminate the need to check file/dir exist.

Comment: `i=~/public/*` will work. It's just that `~` is not expanded inside double quotes.

Comment: The 'bonus' about using an array to glob with whitespace is very cool.  Is this officially documented, or did you discover by chance?

Comment: @kevinarpe, I think arrays are basically meant for just that, and yes, `"${array[@]}"` (with the quotes!) is documented (see [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Arrays.html) and [here](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Arrays)) to expand to the elements as distinct words without splitting them further.

Comment: `x="/tm*"` might work, but `x="/tm{p,q}"` doesn't. Is there a way to make that work, too?

Comment: @sixtyfive, brace expansion happens before variable expansion, so no. But in that particular case (with single-character variation and if you're looking for existing files) you can use `x="/tmp[pq]"`.

Comment: Thanks, ilkkachu, I didn't even know about `[]`. Would make a good addition to the answer, too! :)

Comment: @sixtyfive, well, `[abc]` is a standard part of [glob patterns](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Patterns), like `?`, I don't think it's necessary to go cover all of them here.

Comment: There is a kinda-glob() function in bash... it's called compgen -G
I added an answer below

Answer (score 7):

You can save it as an array instead of a string to use later in many cases and let the globbing happen when you define it.  In your case, for example:

```bsh
k=(~/code/public/*/*.launch)
for i in "${k[@]}"; do
```

or in the later example, you'll need to `eval` some of the strings

```bsh
dirs=(~/code/private/* ~/code/public/*)
for i in "${dirs[@]}"; do
    for j in $exclude; do
        eval "for k in $i/$j; do tmutil addexclusion \"\$k\"; done"
    done
done
```

Comment: Note how `$exclude` contains wildcards, you'd need to disable globbing before using the _split+glob_ operator on it and restore it for the `$i/$j` and _not_ use `eval` but use `"$i"/$j`

Comment: Both you and ilkkachu give good answer. However his answer identified the issue. So credit to him.

Answer (score 3):

With `zsh`:

```bash
exclude='
*.launch
.classpath
.sass-cache
Thumbs.db
...
'

dirs=(
~/code/private/*
~/code/public/*
)

for f ($^dirs/${^${=~exclude}}(N)) {
  echo $f
}
```

`${^array}string` is to expand as `$array[1]string $array[2]string...`. `$=var` is to perform word splitting on the variable (something other shells do by default!), `$~var` does globbing on the variable (something other shells also by default (when you generally don't want them to, you'd have had to quote `$f` above in other shells)).

`(N)` is a glob qualifier that turns on *nullglob* for each of those globs resulting from that `$^array1/$^array2` expansion. That makes the globs expand to nothing when they don't match. That also happens to turn a non-glob like `~/code/private/foo/Thumbs.db` into one, which means that if that particular doesn't exist, it's not included.

Comment: This is really nice. I tested and works. However, it seems zsh is more sensitive to newline when using single quote. The way `exclude` is enclosed is affecting the output.

Comment: @JohnSiu, oh yes, you're right. It seems the split+glob and the `$^array` must be done in two separate steps to make sure the empty elements are discarded (see edit). That looks a bit like a bug in `zsh`, I'll raise the issue on their mailing list.

Comment: I come up with a v2 for bash, which is cleaner, but still not as compact as your zsh script, lol

Answer (score 2):

@ilkkachu answer solved the main globbing issue. Full credit to him.

## V1

However, due to `exclude` containing entries both with and without wildcard(*), and also they may not exist in all, extra checking is needed after the globbing of `$i/$j`. I am sharing my findings here.

```
#!/bin/bash
exclude="
*.launch
.DS_Store
.classpath
.sass-cache
.settings
Thumbs.db
bower_components
build
connect.lock
coverage
dist
e2e/*.js
e2e/*.map
libpeerconnection.log
node_modules
npm-debug.log
testem.log
tmp
typings
"

dirs="
$HOME/code/private/*
$HOME/code/public/*
"

# loop $dirs
for i in $dirs; do
    for j in $exclude ; do
        for k in $i/$j; do
            echo -e "$k"
            if [ -f $k ] || [ -d $k ] ; then
                # Only execute command if dir/file exist
                echo -e "\t^^^ Above file/dir exist! ^^^"
            fi
        done
    done
done
```

## Output Explaination

Following is the partial output to explain the situation.

```
/Volumes/HD2/JS/code/public/simple-api-example-ng2-express/a.launch
    ^^^ Above file/dir exist! ^^^
/Volumes/HD2/JS/code/public/simple-api-example-ng2-express/b.launch
    ^^^ Above file/dir exist! ^^^
/Volumes/HD2/JS/code/public/simple-api-example-ng2-express/.DS_Store
    ^^^ Above file/dir exist! ^^^
```

The above are self explanatory.

```
/Volumes/HD2/JS/code/public/simple-api-example-ng2-express/.classpath
/Volumes/HD2/JS/code/public/simple-api-example-ng2-express/.sass-cache
/Volumes/HD2/JS/code/public/simple-api-example-ng2-express/.settings
/Volumes/HD2/JS/code/public/simple-api-example-ng2-express/Thumbs.db
/Volumes/HD2/JS/code/public/simple-api-example-ng2-express/bower_components
/Volumes/HD2/JS/code/public/simple-api-example-ng2-express/build
/Volumes/HD2/JS/code/public/simple-api-example-ng2-express/connect.lock
/Volumes/HD2/JS/code/public/simple-api-example-ng2-express/coverage
/Volumes/HD2/JS/code/public/simple-api-example-ng2-express/dist
```

The above show up because the exclude entry(`$j`) has no wildcard, `$i/$j` become a plain string concatenation. However the file/dir does not exist.

```
/Volumes/HD2/JS/code/public/simple-api-example-ng2-express/e2e/*.js
/Volumes/HD2/JS/code/public/simple-api-example-ng2-express/e2e/*.map
```

The above show up as exclude entry(`$j`) contain wildcard but has no file/directory match, the globbing of `$i/$j` just return the original string.

## V2

V2 use single quote, `eval` and `shopt -s nullglob` to get clean result. No file/dir final checking require.

```
#!/bin/bash
exclude='
*.launch
.sass-cache
Thumbs.db
bower_components
build
connect.lock
coverage
dist
e2e/*.js
e2e/*.map
libpeerconnection.log
node_modules
npm-debug.log
testem.log
tmp
typings
'

dirs='
$HOME/code/private/*
$HOME/code/public/*
'

for i in $dirs; do
    for j in $exclude ; do
        shopt -s nullglob
        eval "k=$i/$j"
        for l in $k; do
            echo $l
        done
        shopt -u nullglob
    done
done
```

Comment: One problem is that in `for j in $exclude`, the globs in `$exclude` could get expanded at the time of that `$exclude` expansion (and calling `eval` on that is asking for trouble). You'd want globbing enabled for `for i in $dir`, and `for l in $k`, but not for `for j in $exclude`. You'd want a `set -f` before the latter and a `set +f` for the other. More generally, you'd want to tune your split+glob operator before using it. In any case, you don't want split+glob for `echo $l`, so `$l` should be quoted there.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas are you refering to v1 or v2? For v2, both `exclude` and `dirs` are in single quote(`), so no globbing till `eval`.

Comment: [Globbing takes place upon unquoted variable _expansion_ in list contexts](/q/171346), that (leaving a variable unquoted) is what we sometimes call the _split+glob_ operator. There's no globbing in assignments to scalar variables. `foo=*` and `foo='*'` is the same. But `echo $foo` and `echo "$foo"` are not (in shells like `bash`, it's been fixed in shells like zsh, fish or rc, see also the link above). Here you _do_ want to use that operator, but in some places only the split part, and in others only the glob part.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Thanks for the info!!! Took me sometime but I understand the concern now. This very valuable!! Thank you!!!

Answer (score 2):

Old post but I stumbled in here so thought this may help others :)

There is a kinda-glob() function in bash... it's called compgen -G
It outputs a value per line so needs a readarray to work.

Try this:

```
i='~/code/public/*'
j='*.launch'
k=$i/$j # $k='~/code/public/*/*.launch'
readarray -t files < <(compgen -G "$k") # $k is globbed here
for i in "${files[@]}"
do
    echo "Found -$i-"
done
```

Comment: files=($(compgen -G "$pattern")) a better option ? readarray not found in macos