# Listing filenames with wildcards and spaces

Tags: bash

I need to be able to list files as specified in a variable, like in this example:

```bsh
X="myfile.txt"
$ ls ${X}
```

Regrettably, some people use spaces in filenames, so this could be the case:

```bsh
X="my file.txt"
```

which solvable with `ls "${X}"`

However, this could also happen:

```bsh
X="my file.*"
```

which would break because wildcards don't expand within double quotes.

Is there anything that could work in all cases?

**EDIT**

Declaring `X` as an array, as in

```bsh
X=("my file."*)
ls "$X[@]"
```

is not sufficient, because it expands the wildcard at the moment of declaration. I need it to expand when it is used by `ls`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use wildcards, using a variable is not a good idea, because it might match multiple files.

Solution: Use an array!

```bsh
X=("my file."*)
ls "${X[@]}"

# or

for f in "${X[@]}"; do
   some_command "$f"
done
```

Note, that on assignment, the `*` must be outside the quotes.

Check [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/314804/how-to-make-bash-glob-a-string-variable) for solutions that will expand the glob only on variable expansion.

Comment: I just realised that your answer is correct for how I posted the question, but it's not what I was after. The issue is that the wildcard is expanded when `X` is declared, while I need it to expand when `ls` is called.

Comment: Added `eval` option, However, I would not do that!

Comment: Right! I had thought of `eval`, but had failed to make it work. I'm aware `eval` can be evil, I'll use with care.

Comment: @pLumo, the command injection vulnerability is caused by your use of the _unquoted_ `$X` on the `eval` command line. With the value unquoted, it gets word-split into `"my` and `file."*`, with both globbed immediately after. If the latter part matches a filename, e.g. one called `file."$(date >&2)`, the filename will be passed expanded to `eval`, and then `eval` will happily run the command substitution. That wouldn't happen if you prevented wordsplitting and globbing before `eval`, with e.g. `eval "ls -l $X"`.

Comment: Of course if the value of `$X` is not in your control, it's worse, but in this case, the issue happens even _if `X` is fixed to the value shown_. So, **1) quote the variable expansions, 2) take care to reason to the end how a command with `eval` works**, and the corollary **2a) don't use `eval` so you don't have to do that.** (And 3) if possible, use an actual programming language with less landmines.)

Comment: (If `eval` gets multiple arguments, it joins them with spaces, a bit like `echo foo bar` is similar to `echo "foo bar"`. That's why get away with `eval ls -l $X` in the simple case, letting you leave the door open for the cases where it blows you up.)

Comment: @ikkachu, sure you're right. You are allowed to edit my answer :-) I added the `eval` example only because OP explicitely asked for a solution. I removed it again, because it has its own problems even if you neglect the command injection stuff.

Answer (score 2):

### bash

In `bash`, leaving a variable unquoted is sometimes referred to as the split+glob operator.

The split part can be tuned with the `$IFS` special parameter and the glob part with the `noglob` option:

For globbing only, set `$IFS` to the empty string:

```
file_pattern='foo bar *.txt'
IFS= # disable splitting
set +o noglob # make sure glob is enabled
ls -ld -- $file_pattern # split+glog with split disabled.
```

Beware that if the pattern doesn't match any file, `ls` will receive a literal `foo bar *.txt` argument and complain that that file doesn't exist¹.

For splitting only (here to split the colon-separated `$PATH` variable as an example), set the `noglob` option:

```
IFS=: # split on :
set -o noglob
ls -ld -- $PATH # split+glob with glob disabled
```

When `$var` is empty (or unset), note that its expansion when unquoted results in no argument at all instead of one empty argument, even when `$IFS` is empty.

It's acceptable here for `$PATH` as an empty `$PATH` (but not an unset `$PATH`) means commands are searched in the current working directory, and `ls` also happens to list the current working directory when not passed any argument.

If there are empty elements in `$PATH` (as in `/bin::/usr/bin`), which also means the current working directory, a corresponding empty argument will be passed to `ls` which will complain about it. An exception to that is if that empty element is the last (as in `/bin:/usr/bin:`) where that last element is discarded.

A more correct way to split `$PATH`-like variables is to use:

```
IFS=:
set -o noglob
printf '<%s>\n' $PATH''
```

Where that extra `''` prevents the stripping of trailing empty elements and also makes sure an empty `$PATH` is split into one empty element instead of no element at all.

### zsh

In zsh, splitting and globbing are not done implicitly upon parameter expansion, you have to request them explicitly with `$=var` for `$IFS`-splitting, `${(s[separator])var}` for splitting based on one arbitrary separator, `$~var` for globbing (or `$=~var` to combine `$IFS`-splitting and globbing).

So:

```
file_pattern='foo bar *.txt'
ls -ld -- $~file_pattern
```

(if the pattern doesn't match any file, the `ls` command is aborted²).

```
IFS=:
ls -ld -- $=PATH # preserves all empty elements even trailing ones
```

```
ls -ld -- ${(s[:])PATH}    # split, discarding empty elements
ls -ld -- "${(@s[:])PATH}" # split, preserving empty elements
```

---

<sup>¹ unless the `failglob` option (from the other set of option managed by `shopt` instead of `set`) is enabled in which case bash will abort (exit the subshell or skip all the code it has already read if not running in a subshell), or the `nullglob` `shopt` option is enabled in which case it will expand to nothing causing `ls` to list the current working directory.</sup>

<sup>² in zsh, a failing glob is treated similarly to a syntax error, the corresponding shell process exits with an error and a failure exit status (though in interactive shells, it would return to the prompt rather than exit the main shell). Here, as `ls` is an external command, it's only the child process that was spawned to execute it that is aborted, as that's where the glob expansion takes place. It would be different if you had redefined `ls` as a shell function for instance.</sup>